# arguments.callee not returning a callable function when async

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have been playing around with `arguments.callee` and stumbled upon this problem.

My idea was that the anonymous function would run on startup and then again after a few seconds.

```js
setTimeout(async function() {
  console.log('Not working')
  return arguments.callee
}(), 1000)
```

I have no issues if my anonymous function isn't `async`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Working just fine')
  return arguments.callee
}(), 1000)
```

The thing has me baffled is that, when I `console.log(arguments.callee)` in the `async` function, it comes up just fine.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(arguments.callee)
}, 1000)

setTimeout(async function() {
  console.log(arguments.callee)
}, 2000)
```

Can anyone explain to me why it doesn't work when the function is `async`?

Comment: Well the first one returns you a promise containing arguments.callee as part of the result, and a promise isn't diretly callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you return something from an `async` function it is wrapped in a ***Promise***, so the `arguments.callee` is actually the function you want to return but it is wrapped inside a promise.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously
>   via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result.

```js
(async function() {
  console.log('Not working')
  return arguments.callee
}()).then((fun) => fun());
//the wrapped function can be executed in the chained then callback
```

As @ Oliver Nybo pointed out in the comment, we can also use `await` inside an `async` context to wait for the promise to be resolved with the function value:

```js
(async () => {
  setTimeout(await async function() {
    console.log('Not working');
    return arguments.callee;
  }(), 1000)
})();
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense, thank you! I will accept it as the answer as soon as the timer wears off.

Comment: What also works is placing `await` in front of my `async` function like this `setTimeout(await async function() {
  console.log('Now working')
  return arguments.callee
}(), 1000)`

Comment: ^^ as long as it's inside an `async` function of course.

Comment: @OliverNybo absolutely, may I add this observation of yours in my answer?